# Is this site going to spend a second week in private beta?

Tags: support, beta

It's been 7 days and 3 hours since the private beta began. Does this mean that the private beta is going to continue for another week?

(I know that 3 hours isn't very long, but Buddhism's public beta began 7 days and 26 minutes after launch, so I figure it's worth checking.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is!

For details on *why*, see: [Private beta extended - please focus on quality](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/private-beta-extended-please-focus-on-quality)